# Can't retrieve email from session after callback from SoundCloud API

Tags: php, api, soundcloud

When  I first land on the page containing the following code(henceforth read: connect_callback.php) the proper email gets retrieved and displayed from session. But when the call is returned to the page from the soundcloud page, the email is displayed as NULL. I need the email id to insert the relevant data into the database. I'm unable to figure out a way around to get this to work.

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/Soundcloud.php';

session_start();

$email = $_SESSION[`email`];
//var_dump($email);
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$callback = "XXXXXXXXX";

$soundcloud = new Services_SoundCloud($clientId,$clientSecret,$callback);
$soundcloud->setDevelopment(false);
$authURL = $soundcloud->getAuthorizeUrl();
//echo "<pre>";
echo "<a href='$authURL'>Connect to SoundCloud</a>";

//Attempt tp get token from Session First
//Set the token otherwise...
try{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])){
        $accessToken = $soundcloud->accessToken($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['access_token'];
    }
    else{
        $soundcloud->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }
}
catch(Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e){
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

try{
    $me = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me'), true);
    //print_r($me);

    $user_data = array(
                'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
                'id' => $me['id']
                );

    $tracks = json_decode($soundcloud->get('tracks', array('user_id' => $user_data['id'])), true);

    //print_r($tracks);
    $htmlBody .= '<h3>Your Track List</h3><form action="upload_soundcloudlinks.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$email.'" />';

    foreach($tracks as $track){
        /*echo $track['permalink_url'];
        $song = $track['permalink_url'];*/
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="soundcloud[]" value="%s">%s<br>', $track['permalink_url'],$track['title']);
    }

    $htmlBody .= '<input type="submit" value="Upload These" /></form>';
    /*$user_tracks = array(
                        'link' => $tracks['permalink_url'];
                    );
    print_r($tracks['permalink_url']);*/
}
catch(Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e){
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Uploads</title>
</head>
<body>
<?=$htmlBody?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your htmlbody you are using $_GET, you should use the same $email variable or set it from $_SESSION.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that before posting it here. I've now made the change. I've set the email from the session in 4th line of the code which is getting reset after the call is returned